# Honeycomb Action Bar not showing (baffled)

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am completely baffled. I created an application with minSDK=4 and targetSDK=11. Compiled and ran on the Xoom tablet. I am not getting an Action Bar and cannot figure out what I have done wrong. I have been staring at the screen for hours and don't know what I have done that would have caused the bar to disappear. Help! Any suggestions on why I am not seeing the Action Bar?

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working, and also check logcat for any clues and post those as well. Without a little more information it's almost impossible to determine the possible cause. It's also worth mentioning that if you're using the Android ActionBar class, this is **only** supported in API level 11 onwards, and you'll need to detect and handle this gracefully on OS version prior to 11.

Comment: Also look at the API demos samples, e.g. FragmentLayout to see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: Well, I guess this is the problem because, according to the docs... "In this example, the application requires a minimum version of API Level 4 (Android 1.6), but it also targets API Level 11 (Android 3.0). This way, when the application is installed on a device running Android 3.0 or greater, the system applies the holographic theme to each activity, and thus, each activity includes the Action Bar." So I really didn't do anything to my application as I was under the impression that the Action Bar just appeared.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a problem somewhere in my theme...

Comment: Yes, now ringing bells. You need the Holo theme. See first line of "Adding the Action Bar" at [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: Yeah, I changed the base theme to Holo but that still does not fix the problems. I removed the reference in the manifest to my theme and the action bar shows up. I am still lost...

Comment: Freaken typo... <style name="themename" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"> should have been <style name="Theme.themename" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

Comment: Mind to put it into a answer and accept it for other people to easier find it? Thx

Answer (score 11):

You need to declare `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` for `Activity` in Manifest xml.

The dev guide says like you only need to set the target SDK version, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Romulus' answer, forcing the App to use the Holo theme will work but it results in a compile error if your `minSDK` is less than 11.

Check if you have defined a theme in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
android:theme="@style/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

That means you're forcing the App to use a particular theme, so the action bar might not appear on Honeycomb or higher devices (it depends if the theme specifies an action bar). Delete this statement to cause the App to use the default device theme, so the Settings menu appears on pre-Honeycomb devices and the action bar appears on post-Honeycomb devices. Job done. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html):
"If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar, then you must use (or override) the Theme.AppCompat family of styles (rather than the Theme.Holo family, available in API level 11 and higher)."

I used `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in my manifest and the action bar appeared.